# How to multiply by 2 a 32 bit signed std_logic_vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

We have a type which is an array of 32 bit "std_logic_vector" of size 3, which is defined in the following way:

```
subtype scalar is std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
type vector_nd is array (natural range <>) of scalar;
subtype vector_3d is vector_nd(2 downto 0);
```

We have a signal of type "vector_3d" which we want to multiply by 2 and put the result in a signal of type "scalar":

```
signal v_normal_out_sig := vector_3d;
signal mult1_in1_sig    := scalar;
--...
mult1_in1_sig <= 2*signed(v_normal_out_sig(0)) when cau_state = st_cycle18;
```

When we compile it we get the error:

```
No feasible entries for infix operator "*".
```

What is the right way to implement what we want? We are using the following libraries:

- ieee.std_logic_1164.all
- ieee.std_logic_arith.all
- ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all

Comment: You could simply left-shift your `v_normal_out_sig(0)` signal by 1 bit to achieve a multiplication by 2. Consider using the functions provided by the `numeric_std` library (i.e. `SHIFT_LEFT`).

Comment: @simon, those are signed numbers, I can't just Shift Left as I'll lose the sign bit. We implemented our own "shift left", shown in the answer.

Comment: Ilya, most languages have bit shift operations that preserve the sign (not sure about VHDL).

Comment: The `SHIFT_LEFT` function takes care of that. However, your own function should also be fine. I'd still suggest making use of the `numeric_std` functions for cleaner and (arguably) better readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did eventually is the fallowing:

```
mult1_in1_sig <= v_normal_out_sig(0)(31) & v_normal_out_sig(0)(29 downto 0) & '0' when cau_state = st_cycle18;
```

And test gave the right results for both positive and negative numbers.